# Set minimum height for SliverAppBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I decrease the height of SliverAppBar in Flutter? For example, I want to set the height for SliverAppBar equal to 40. This height is less than the default height of SliverAppBar.

This is the code:

```dart
SliverAppBar(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  titleSpacing: 0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  pinned: true,
  actions: <Widget>[
    Container()
  ],
  expandedHeight: 40,
  stretch: true,
  title: Container(
    height: 40,
    width: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You set expandedHeight to 40. And you wrote that 40 "is less than the default height of SliverAppBar". So you need to change this value to for example 100:

```
SliverAppBar(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  titleSpacing: 0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  pinned: true,
  actions: <Widget>[
    Container()
  ],
  expandedHeight: 100,
  stretch: true,
  title: Container(
    height: 40,
    width: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

Is that, what did you mean?

In documentation, there is a sample with FlexibleSpaceBar. Maybe this will be a better approach for you:

```
SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 100.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Container(
                height: 40,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

You can also use collapsedHeight method of SliverAppBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `toolBarHeight` property of the AppBar.

As the documentation says:

> Defines the height of the toolbar component of an AppBar.

Check: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/toolbarHeight.html

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information in the link provided in the answer itself. This helps to ensure your answer doesn't become invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.